# Android studio altera mis archivos al abrirlos

Tags: android-studio

El problema es que hoy al abrir mi proyecto, android studio alteraba mis archivos java, xml, y los del gradle, en algunos incluso ponía código de librerías.

Al abrir los archivos con windows estos están bien, no tengo idea de que pueda ser, pero al momento de abrir el proyecto android studio y abrir un archivo los altera, alguna idea de que pueda ser?, el error que ocurre en el IDE se encuentra abajo de las screenshots
[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error ocurre al abrir un archivo en el IDE:

### Existe alguna solucion

```
com.intellij.psi.stubs.UpToDateStubIndexMismatch: PSI and index do not match.
Please report the problem to JetBrains with the files attached
INDEXED VERSION IS THE CURRENT ONE file=PsiJavaFile:Constantes_Links.java, file.class=class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileImpl, file.lang=Language: JAVA, modStamp=4
 tree consistent
 stub debugInfo=created in getStubTree(), with AST = false; with backReference
latestIndexedStub=StubTree{myDebugInfo='created from index; with backReference', myRoot=PsiJavaFileStub [xxx.xx.x.inventario.Constantes]}1076188414
   same size=true
   debugInfo=created from index; with backReference
 viewProvider=SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://C:/Users/carlo/AndroidStudioProjects/xx/app/src/main/java/xxx/xx/x/d/Constantes/Constantes_Links.java, content=VirtualFileContent{size=201}}
 viewProvider stamp: 0; file stamp: 0; file modCount: 1578704978687; file length: 201
 doc saved: true; doc stamp: 0; doc size: 196; committed: true
indexing info: indexed at 1578704978687 with document size 196
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubTreeLoader.handleUpToDateMismatch(StubTreeLoader.java:148)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubTreeLoader.stubTreeAndIndexDoNotMatch(StubTreeLoader.java:141)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.FileTrees.reconcilePsi(FileTrees.java:201)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.FileTrees.withAst(FileTrees.java:149)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.loadTreeElement(PsiFileImpl.java:214)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.calcTreeElement(PsiFileImpl.java:714)
    at com.intellij.extapi.psi.StubBasedPsiElementBase.getNode(StubBasedPsiElementBase.java:142)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassImpl.getNode(PsiClassImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassImpl.getNode(PsiClassImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.JavaStubPsiElement.calcTreeElement(JavaStubPsiElement.java:51)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.JavaStubPsiElement.getTextOffset(JavaStubPsiElement.java:47)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.EditSourceUtil.getDescriptor(EditSourceUtil.java:55)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.PsiNavigationSupportImpl.getDescriptor(PsiNavigationSupportImpl.java:25)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementBase.navigate(PsiElementBase.java:195)
    ...more
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.performPsiModification(DebugUtil.java:562)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.FileTrees.reconcilePsi(FileTrees.java:182)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: podrias subir un screenshot de como los mezclaba?

Comment: acabo de subir 2

Comment: al parecer al cabo de un tiempo, todos mis proyectos acaban igual

Comment: el peor ide que he usado

Comment: y cabe aclarar que los archivos no contienen lo que el ide me muestra, por lo menos no los altero, solo que al abrirlos no muestra lo que en realidad tienen

Comment: Perdon, pero en esos xml no logro ver nada "mezclado". Si tenes problemas para compilar el codigo probablemente se deba a las versiones de sdk y java que se van actualizando y no todas son compatibles con todas, entonces los proyectos mas viejos dejan de funcionar si no los actualizas.

Comment: bueno, no estan mezclados, no era el termino correcto, mas bien alterados al abrirlos en el IDE, y no tengo problemas para compilar la aplicacion, si vuelvo a abrir el proyecto, mientras no abra ningun archivo, la aplicacion la puedo compilar, pero si abro un archivo se altera como en las imagenes, y ya no puedo compilarlo

Comment: acabo de agregar el error que ocurre al abrir los archivos

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo lo que comentas, en realidad esto se debe a un error al construir el proyecto, por ejemplo cuando cargas el proyecto se realizan ciertos procesos para realizar relaciones entre los elementos del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en ocasiones puede ocurrir un error o simplemente no realizarse el proceso completo, en este caso ocurre lo que mencionas, abres por ejemplo un archivo .java desde Android Studio y te muestra contenido de un archivo .xml.

Lo que tienes que realizar para solucionar esta situación es "limpiar" y reconstruir nuevamente tu proyecto

`Build` > `Clean Project`

`Build` > `Rebuild Project`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lamentablemente eso no ayudo, lo que funciono fue copiar el proyecto y pegarlo en otro directorio, al abrirlo todo funciono correctamente, muchas gracias!